# Making a very long word fit in responsive element?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html, multiline

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <h1>VeryLongWordHere</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJTvh/)

---

On mobile screens the text becomes unreadable; leaving me with two options:

1. Make the text size reduce when width gets to certain size (how do I do this BTW?)
2. Make the text go over >1 lines; e.g.: on each segment I specify with `<span>` tags

However I'm not sure how to do either...

Comment: You need to specify what the real content is. If it is a natural language word, it is best handled with hyphenation. If it is computer code or mathematical expressions, it is best handled by inserting codes for allowed line breaks at suitable points.

Comment: Well... it's the domain name.

Comment: The description of the real problem should be in the question, not in a comment. Anyway, if it is a domain name, it should not be divided into lines. So the real problem is: what makes you set such restrictions that prevent a domain name from appearing on one line?

Answer (score 14):

I use this CSS in my solution to a similar problem:

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

This will force words to break if necessary to force them to fit.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good temporary fix. How do I get fine-grained control though; so that "Very" "Long" "Word" are never broken; but can be on same line as eachother?

Comment: In the case of extremely long strings (such as URLs) within potentially narrow containers there is a valid use case for doing this, although you might want to consider making the URL the href of a link which could be labelled in such a way to make it easier to fit in. The W3C certainly feel there is a sufficient use case to add it to the draft standard for CSS3 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap).

Comment: Thanks! That saves me!

Answer (score 1):

For your first option, there are a number of jQuery plugins that dynamically resize text to fit the width of the parent element. Here are a few:

- [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)
- [SlabText](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/)
- [BigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/)

You could use any of these plugins to resize the text when the screen size is smaller than a certain breakpoint. Something like this:

```
if (jQuery(window).width()) < 600) {
   jQuery('h1').slabText();
}
```

Comment: Thanks; so this is only possible with JavaScript? - Is there a CSS solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, the CSS options are pretty limited. Nothing that really comes close to the jQuery options listed above.

Comment: Also, sounds like you're dealing with the domain name. Could you make the domain name into an image and then use width:100% on the image? This would be a CSS-only solution, but the domain name would need to be an image instead of HTML text.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to resize the very long word on small screen sizes (Responsive Screen), min-width could be any minimum width, now if user shrink the screen size then word will break and fit into the screen size.

```css
  .wallet__address {
    min-width: 50px;
    word-break:break-word;
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <div className="wallet__address">
      <p>
        0x1453Dbb0x1453Dbb0x1453Dbb0x1453Dbb0x1453Dbb
      </p>
    </div>
</html>
```